# I don't know how to insert a key into a custom property in Python

Tags: keyframes, custom-properties

I want to insert a keyframe into a custom property that I have set up.

I have tried to do this in past posts, but have not been able to.

Could you please give me some advice?

````
import bpy


value = 10.0
scenes = bpy.data.scenes["Scene"]

scenes.view_layers["rend"]["nodes[\"Brush Settings\"].size"] = value

scenes.view_layers["rend"].keyframe_insert(data_path = '["nodes[\"Brush Settings\"]')
scenes.view_layers["rend"].keyframe_insert(data_path = '["nodes[\"Brush Settings\"].size"]')
scenes.view_layers["rend"].keyframe_insert(data_path = '["nodes["Brush Settings"].size"]')
scenes.view_layers["rend"].keyframe_insert(data_path = '["nodes[Brush Settings].size"]')
```
````